# How to specify the version of output SQLite database in ogr2ogr?

Tags: spatialite, ogr2ogr, sqlite

I'm having issues with a .sqlite database that I generate from PostGIS using ogr2ogr. The data appears to export into SQLite properly, and it loads in TileMill fine, but when I try to add any of the layers in QGIS it tells me:

```
Invalid layer. <layer name> is an invalid layer and cannot be loaded.
```

I was thinking that maybe my version of QGIS is running a slightly older version of SpatiaLite, so I decided to try exporting the data to a different version of SpatiaLite database. Is this an option in ogr2ogr?

Comment: You can check if indeed the problem is with the Spatilite version by converting your .sqlite database to version 3 **after** the export. You would use the spatialite_convert tool: `spatialite_convert -v 3 -d your.sqlite` If that does open in QGIS then you have a newer GDAL (ogr2ogr) which is building a version 4 spatialite database - not readable by QGIS 1.8.0.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I discovered that my issue was that the data didn't have an SRID specified. Once I fixed that in PostGIS, the SQLite export opened fine in QGIS.